# How to do batch retreival of email using Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap or Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap

Tags: php, zend-mail

I am using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap to access email but using following code

```
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);
$allIds = $storage->getUniqueId(); // i get all key value pair of meesageid and uniqueid
foreach ($allIds as $k => $v) 
{
    echo '<li>' . htmlentities($storage->getMessage($v)->subject) . "</li>\n";
}
```

My problem is that it loops and get one email at a time which is slow like getting two emails  per second which is very slow . I am looking for batch retreival method of these mails but could not find any . Did anybody do it before

Comment: did this help you out at all? Can you accept the answer or provide your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.

Where $imap is an instantiated and connected version of Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap:

1. `$imap->select(); // or $imap->select('FOLDER_NAME');`
2. `$imap->requestAndResponse('SEARCH UNSEEN', $imap->escapeString('*'))//all unread email ids`
3. `$imap->requestAndResponse('SEARCH UNSEEN FROM "someEmail@gmail.com"', $imap->escapeString('*'))//all unread email id's from someEmail@gmail.com`
4. `$imap->requestAndResponse('SEARCH UNSEEN SUBJECT "test" FROM "someEmail@gmail.com"', $imap->escapeString('*'))//all unread email id's from someEmail@gmail.com with the subject of test`

*You must do #1 above first or else you'll get something similar to: "TAG# BAD SEARCH not allowed now."

All of the above will return an array similar to the below array:

```c
//C: TAG3 SEARCH UNSEEN
//S: * SEARCH 321 323 362 371 377 384 386 387 388 389 416 417 418 
//S: TAG3 OK SEARCH completed (Success) 
//The above lines are in the format of RFC 1730 to show what was actually sent/received.

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=14)
      0 => string 'SEARCH' (length=6)
      1 => string '321' (length=3)
      2 => string '323' (length=3)
      3 => string '362' (length=3)
      4 => string '371' (length=3)
      5 => string '377' (length=3)
      6 => string '384' (length=3)
      7 => string '386' (length=3)
      8 => string '387' (length=3)
      9 => string '388' (length=3)
      10 => string '389' (length=3)
      11 => string '416' (length=3)
      12 => string '417' (length=3)
      13 => string '418' (length=3)
```